# install npm react icons

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I want to build todo list with react js, but when i install react icons, i got some error
i'm using install `npm install react-icons --save` . Is that wrong?

Can i get some alternate to solved this code?
this is my error

```
PS C:\xampp\htdocs\TodoReactJS\todoreactjs> npm install react-icons --save
npm WARN @apideck/better-ajv-errors@0.3.6 requires a peer of ajv@>=8 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin@6.5.3 requires a peer of typescript@>= 2.7 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN tsutils@3.21.0 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.3.2 (node_modules\fsevents):
32","arch":"x64"})

+ react-icons@4.10.1
updated 1 package and audited 1501 packages in 21.147s

236 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 1 high severity vulnerability
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

Comment: Can you show the `package.json`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not an error. These warnings are due to the dependencies conflict, you can't do anything much about it, as there is a big dependency tree that could only be fixed from the package manager intervention.

Comment: okey solved, i just import the icons, not with install npm there

Answer (score 0):

Look for `"dependencies": {"react-icons": "^4.10.1"}` in your package.json.

If the package exists, then you can import as follow:

```
import { RiHome2Line } from 'react-icons/ri';
```

Comment: ooh i see, thanks to information